Firefox problem after Ubuntu update
The display of Firefox expands from time to time, so some of the buttons, such as Back and side scroll tabs, are no longer visible. I can get it to revert to normal by clicking on the reduce window button and then bringing it back to normal size, but it is really annoying to keep having to do that all the time.
Any idea of the cause and remedy anyone?
It started after one of the updates to Ubuntu 22.04.

This may be a snap issue. Install Firefox as a traditional deb package instead https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/124466

I've see this in various applications, rarely but once in a great while firefox as well.  This is probably not going to be an issue generic to all Ubuntu.  It is more likely to be associated with the desktop environment.  That could be Gnome for Ubuntu, XFCE for Xubuntu or perhaps whatever the desktop is for Kubuntu.   Please indicate which desktop environment is being used to consistently see this problem.
